# Compact sets in a normed vector space (compactness property)

Tags: functional-analysis

Is it true that in a normed vector space compact sets (which are closed and bounded) are finite dimensional?

Comment: What does it mean for you for a set to be finite dimensional?

Comment: Certainly not true. Let $(e_n)$ be any linearly independent set of unit vectors and consider $K=\{0,e_1/1,e_2/2,...\}$.

Comment: Closed and bounded sets need not be compact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably got something confused. There is Heine-Borel's theorem:
If $V$ is a normed vector space, then
$$
B_1(0) := \lbrace v \in V: \lVert v \rVert_V \leq 1 \rbrace \text{ is compact }\iff \dim V < \infty.
$$
In the space of $\ell^2$ of real sequences whose square is summable, the *hilbert cube*
$$
C := \left \lbrace x \in \ell^2 : \lvert x_n \rvert \leq \frac{1}{n} ~\forall n \in \mathbb{N} \right \rbrace
$$
is infinite-dimensional and compact.

Answer (score 0):

It is true that if in some topological vector space exists a compact nieghborhood of zero then the dimension of this topological vector space is finite. Particulary if yoh have a normed space then the unit closed unit ball is a bounded  neighborhood of zero so if you assume that in some normed space the any closed and bounded set is compact then the space must be finite dimensional. But in any normed space exist infinite dimensional sets that are compact to see this it is enough to consider any convergent sequence consists of linearrly independent vectors with its limit.

Comment: What notion of dimension are you using here? In what sense is a sequence infinite dimensional?